# Action filters to supply common data to Views in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get some common properties to all my Views that derive from `ViewModelBase`. Except I ran into a sort of Catch-22...

The common properties of my `ViewModelBase` are: `User` and `Environment` (there are more, but for this question these two would suffice).

Right now, I have a global filter that assigns these two properties - the `ViewModelBase.User` property is assigned from `BaseController.User`, which was previously assigned by an Authorization Filter.

It works well in all cases, but this: The Authorization Filter some times based on business logic decides to redirect the user to the "not yet approved" page. This is done like so:

```
var notApprovedView = new ViewResult();
notApprovedView.ViewName = "NotYetApproved";
filterContext.Result = notApprovedView;
```

Except, in this case, the ViewModel does not yet have the common property that was supposed to be assigned by the Global filter, which results in a run-time exception.

What's the proper (i.e. best practice, not hack) way to deal with a situation where I need common properties assigned and some of the common properties may change depending on authorization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have missed the forest for the trees on this one... Sorry.

I could just do the following in the Authorization Filter:

```
var notApprovedView = new ViewResult();
notApprovedView.ViewName = "NotYetApproved";

// add this line    
notApprovedView.Model = new ViewModelBase(){User = this.user};

filterContext.Result = notApprovedView;
```